# Javascript night mode - Click function that changes background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm coding a website and I want to be able to switch between day mode and nigth mode. It's not working, I need help here. Thank you in advance.

**HTML**

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="chk" />
<label class="label" for="chk">
    <i class="fas fa-moon"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-sun"></i>
    <div class="ball"></div>
</label>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#chk").click(function(){
    $("body").css("background-color", "black");
  });
});
```

Comment: "not working" is a poor description of a problem. Please tell us exactly what you expect to happen that isn't, what's happening that you weren't expecting, etc.. See [ask] for more tips to avoid getting your question closed and/or downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

In your method, when the `<input>` element's click event fires, the `<body>` element's background color is constantly assigned `black`; this behavior does not create a toggle effect.

###### Method-1

You can switch between day and night modes using the change event of the `<input>` element:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  function changeColor(newBgColor) {
    $("#sun").css({color: newBgColor});
    $("#moon").css({color: newBgColor});
  }

  /* When the <input> element's change event fires */
  $('#chk').change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
      $("body").css("background-color", "black");
      changeColor("white");
    }
    else {
      $("body").css("background-color", "white");
      changeColor("black");
    }
  });  
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-Fo3rlrZj/k7ujTnHg4CGR2D7kSs0v4LLanw2qksYuRlEzO+tcaEPQogQ0KaoGN26/zrn20ImR1DfuLWnOo7aBA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="chk" />
  
  <label class="label">
      <i id="moon" class="fas fa-moon"></i>
      <i id="sun" class="fas fa-sun"></i>
      <div class="ball"></div>
  </label>
</div>
```

###### Method-2

You can get around this by giving the `<i>` elements an `id`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  function changeColor(newBgColor) {
    $("#sun").css({color: newBgColor});
    $("#moon").css({color: newBgColor});
  }
  
  /* Fires when clicking <i> with id value of "sun" */
  $("#sun").click(function(){
    $("body").css("background-color", "black");
    changeColor("white");
  });
  
  /* Fires when clicking <i> with id value of "moon" */
  $("#moon").click(function(){
    $("body").css("background-color", "white");
    changeColor("black");
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-Fo3rlrZj/k7ujTnHg4CGR2D7kSs0v4LLanw2qksYuRlEzO+tcaEPQogQ0KaoGN26/zrn20ImR1DfuLWnOo7aBA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <label class="label">
      <i id="moon" class="fas fa-moon"></i>
      <i id="sun" class="fas fa-sun"></i>
      <div class="ball"></div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use a css rule to make the background black (.black) and use [toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to make it work

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#chk").click(function(){
    $("body").toggleClass('black');
  });
});
```

```css
.black { background-color:#000 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="chk" />
<label class="label" for="chk">
    <i class="fas fa-moon"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-sun"></i>
    <div class="ball"></div>
</label>
```